# why is String(format:"....", "...") not displaying the second "..." argument

Tags: swift, string

I am using the following code:

```
narrative.text = String(format: "\(reviewNumber!)", "\(LoopNo + 2)")
```

The above displays only the first number, but not the second one. Any idea what I have to use instead? Is this because of Xcode 8.3?

My actual problem is that I am using this in connection with NSLocalizedString:

```
 narrative.text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("noCards", comment: "No cards in Compartment "), reviewCompartment)
```

Comment: The first string is not a format string..

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just create a string, or are you trying to format?

Comment: The code you posted would give you the same result under every version of Xcode that has ever supported any version of Swift. This misuse of `String(format:)` has nothing to do with Xcode 8.3.

Comment: Based on your updated question it seems you completely misunderstand the use of `String(format:)`. The first argument must be a format string that contains one or more format specifiers and the rest of the arguments must correspond to those format specifiers. In both lines of code in your question, your format string has no format specifiers.

Comment: Gentlemen, this was indeed me not getting the String(format:) at all. I get it now and I am now using 
narrative.text = String(NSLocalizedString("noCards", comment: "No cards in Compartment ")) + "\(reviewCompartment)")
and this works perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to write it using the proper syntax, like this:

```
narrative.text = String(format: "%d%d", reviewNumber!, LoopNo + 2)
```

Or, you can just write it like this:

```
narrative.text = "\(reviewNumber!) \(LoopNo + 2)"
```

Comment: Yes, sure, but why does it not work? I am actually using this in connection with NSLocalizedString where I have to use String(format:) to deal with the variable.
    narrative.text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("noCards", comment: "No cards in Compartment "), reviewCompartment)

Comment: Are you using Swift 2.3?

Comment: @kangarooChris I don't think you understand the that `format` in "String(format:)` does, which is the underlying issue causing all this confusion.